# How can I update a nested field in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm quite new to BigQuery and I went through some of the questions which were already being asked, and it was quite confusing on where to start.

So I'd need to update a field that's four levels down the nesting. Something like:

event.group.details.attributes.name → name is the field I need to update.

How should I go about this?

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET event.group.details.attributes =
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT attributes.* REPLACE('some name' AS name))
      (SELECT AS STRUCT attributes.* REPLACE('some value' AS value)))
    FROM UNNEST(event.group.details.attributes) as attributes
  )
WHERE TRUE;
```

And it was throwing me with errors saying:

> Syntax error: Function call cannot be applied to this expression.
> Function calls require a path, e.g. a.b.c() at [6:7]

Comment: It may be easier to go directly to ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to Update using the following query, and didn't realize it was this simple:

```
UPDATE
  `projectid.dataset.table`
SET
  event.group.details.attributes = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT 
      'customer_id'AS name,
      ['1'] AS value
    )
WHERE
  date = "2023-09-28";
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is because your SQL syntax might not be quite right. Can you try using subqueries and the ARRAY function like below? Let know if this works.

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET event.group.details.attributes = ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value STRING>>(
  SELECT AS STRUCT 
    attributes.name AS name,
    CASE 
      WHEN attributes.name = 'name' THEN 'some name'
      ELSE attributes.value
    END AS value
  FROM UNNEST(event.group.details.attributes) AS attributes
)
WHERE TRUE;
```

**EDIT 1**:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET event.group.details.attributes = ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value ARRAY<STRING>>>(
  SELECT AS STRUCT 
    CASE 
      WHEN attributes.name = 'name' THEN 'some name'
      ELSE attributes.name
    END AS name,
    CASE 
      WHEN attributes.name = 'name' THEN attributes.value
      ELSE ['some value']  -- You can replace this with your desired array of values.
    END AS value
  FROM UNNEST(event.group.details.attributes) AS attributes
)
WHERE TRUE;
```

- We use AS STRUCT to define the new structure for each element in the
  array.
- We check if the name is 'name' and replace it with 'some name'
  if it matches.
- We also check if the name is 'name' and replace the
  value with your desired array of values (you can replace ['some
  value'] with your own array of values).
- For other cases where name is
  not 'name', we keep the original name and value fields.

This should allow you to update both the name and value fields within the nested structure.

**EDIT 2**:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET event.group.details.attributes = (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value STRING>>[
    (SELECT AS STRUCT 
      CASE 
        WHEN attr.name = 'name' THEN 'some name'
        ELSE attr.name
      END AS name,
      CASE 
        WHEN attr.name = 'name' THEN 'some value'
        ELSE attr.value
      END AS value)
    FROM UNNEST(event.group.details.attributes) AS attr
  ]
)
WHERE TRUE;
```

**EDIT 3**:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET event.group.details.attributes = (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value ARRAY<STRING>>>[
    (
      SELECT AS STRUCT 
      CASE 
        WHEN attr.name = '' THEN 'some name' ELSE 'some name'
      END AS name,
      CASE 
        WHEN attr.name = 'some name' THEN ['some value'] ELSE ['some value']
      END AS value
    )
  ]
    FROM UNNEST(event.group.details.attributes) AS attr
)
WHERE TRUE;
```

**EDIT 4**:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET event.group.details.attributes = (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value ARRAY<STRING>>>[
    (
      SELECT AS STRUCT 
      IFNULL(attr.name, 'some name') AS name,
      IF(attr.name = 'some name', ['some value'], ['some value']) AS value
    )
  ]
  FROM UNNEST(event.group.details.attributes) AS attr
)
WHERE TRUE;
```

In this version of the query:

- We use IFNULL to update the name field. If attr.name is NULL, it will
  be set to 'some name'.
- We use IF to update the value field. If attr.name is 'some name', it
  will be set to ['some value']; otherwise, it will be set to ['some
  value'].

This approach avoids the need for explicit CASE statements and provides a more concise way to achieve the same result.

Comment: uh basically `name` is a string and `value` is an array of strings. These are the two values I need to update. When I tried yours, I"m getting **Syntax error: Expected "[" but got "(" at [91:78]**

Comment: Oh !! Okay. I have made an edit. Can you try checking that?

Comment: thanks for your effort, but it still shows the same error **Syntax error: Expected "[" but got "(" at [91:85]**

Comment: Let's give it another try. Can you check the EDIT 2 in my updated code?

Comment: hey @Nidheesh with your updated query, again the same issue came.. so i tried to wrap the `(SELECT AS STRUCT...` part with [] and then the query executed. But for some reason the values of the columns did not change. I'll check that further and see. Do you think is there any other way to directly update the value instead of having **CASE** statements? Also I've suggested an edit for your answer with the minor fix (EDIT 3)

Comment: Yeah. We can also use a more direct approach to create the new array. Please check if my EDIT 4 looks helpful.

Comment: @NidheeshR Please don't leave old edits in your answers.  No sense in making people read through old solutions which you've already established don't answer the question.  The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77237296/revisions) will contain the older ones.

Comment: Sure @NotTheDr01ds